# How can I have a collection of emotion stickers in Wordpress comments?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to have a collection of stickers for users to select when they add comments in WordPress. How can I do that? I have done some research in Google but cannot find a solution. All I can find is just a plugin of emoji.

Comment: please show what you have done so far

Comment: Hi, I haven't done anything for stickers. That's why I ask for help on how to start here. I would like to have a collection of stickers below my comment box. When users select a sticker, it will then appear in the comment box. Is there any plugins that do the job?